# How do I label the max value per group in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I have a table with 3 columns:

- Number of clusters (ranges from 1 to 13)
- Type of cluster evaluation metric (can be 5 different values: silhouette, score function, COP, CH and DB)
- Value of evaluation metric for the corresponding number of clusters.

Like this:

| # Clusters | Metric | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Silhouette | 0.15 |
| 2 | Silhouette | 0.22 |
| 3 | Silhouette | 0.20 |
| 4 | Silhouette | ... |
| 5 | Silhouette | ... |
| 6 | Silhouette | ... |
| 7 | Silhouette | ... |
| 8 | Silhouette | ... |
| 9 | Silhouette | ... |
| 10 | Silhouette | ... |
| 11 | Silhouette | ... |
| 12 | Silhouette | ... |
| 13 | Silhouette | ... |
| 1 | SF | 0.45 |
| 2 | SF | 0.23 |
| ... | SF | ... |

So I'd like a point plot or a line plot that highlights the maximum value per metric. Is there an easy way in "label=" to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(Metric) %>%
  summarise(Max=max(Value,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Metric,y=Max))+
  geom_col(fill='cyan3',color='black')+
  geom_text(aes(label=Max),vjust=-0.25)
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(`# Clusters` = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L), Metric = c("Silhouette", "Silhouette", 
"Silhouette", "Silhouette", "Silhouette", "Silhouette", "Silhouette", 
"Silhouette", "Silhouette", "Silhouette", "Silhouette", "Silhouette", 
"Silhouette", "SF", "SF"), Value = c(0.15, 0.22, 0.2, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.45, 0.23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting close! What I'd really prefer is a line or a point plot though, and that the label = "# Clusters", and not the actual value for the metric. Would you know how to tweak your solution to solve that? I've tried a little myself, I can't seem to keep "# Clusters" in the group_by...

Comment: @cherrypie Do you mean x axis clusters, y axis values, and a color for each metric?

Comment: @cherrypie Please try this: `ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(`# Clusters`),y=Value,color=Metric,group=Metric))+geom_line()` using your data `df=yourdata` please check that and let me know if that works!

Comment: @cherrypie The variable number of cluster should use back ticks `